# Memory techniques for torah?

Tags: torah-study, memory

What are some good mnemonics for remembering Talmud and Mishna? The Talmud refers to it as making simanim for what you learn.

Comment: What sort of techniques have you learned, and why cant they be applied directly to Jewish texts?

Comment: I am not sure that this is on topic. It might be better suited for http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ebJlcZMx3c this explains these techniques

Comment: Could you summarize its contents, and specifically what about them is insufficient when applied to Torah studies. Alternatively, what is significant about remembering Torah as opposed to remembering anything else, (and by extension, why is this relevant to this site)?

Comment: but I'm generally looking for any techniques that anyone uses to memorize Talmud or Mishna

Comment: Related: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Arieh Yehuda from Modena wrote a wonderful book called Lev Haarie   about the issue and in his introduction he addressed the midrasdim examples,  Tora niknet besimanim etc..

The Shaar in [Hebrew books](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/37392)

He uses a technic called zikaron hamekomi,  which is not a Jewish/torah royalty

The better mnemonics are always the mnemonic you invented yourself.

To hear yourself and a good pronunciation. Learn again even if you already know it, endlessly, all this is in Talmud. In gemara, there are also sgulot, things that lead to forgetness or to rememberness

article summarizing his views and approach here
[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254157698_Jewish_Traditions_on_Strengthening_Memory_and_Leone_Modena's_Evaluation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254157698_Jewish_Traditions_on_Strengthening_Memory_and_Leone_Modena%27s_Evaluation)

Answer (score 5):

R Jonathan Rietti has an excellent book on Torah learning called the [One minute masmid](http://a.co/8BLr27Q). In appendix D (p. 241) he brings 43 strategies recommended by Chazal to improve memory - with their sources. Here are the first 10 of those, see the book for more

1. Constantly review your learning
2. Read your learning out loud
3. Sing your learning
4. Engage your mind in the words as you speak
5. Write down your own insights
6. Make your own summary of your learning and then make a code work to represent that information
7. Under-eating and avoiding food that does not support your health
8. Learn in a modest way (without trying to impress others)
9. Learn in a *beit hamidrash* or *shul*
10. Learn *lishma* - with intent to apply what you learn

etc.

Comment: Good answer, I was looking for a specific strategy using mnemonics for memorizing Talmud. The sefer listed in the first answer was the answer.